# How do I sort the column from large to small numerically?

Tags: sorting, parameters, abap

I get a variable number of data from the user with the parameter. I want to sort (descending ascending) them among themselves. I tried using **order by**, but I don't know how to solve it.

My data is separated as follows:

`SPLIT sayilar AT '-' INTO TABLE it_char.`

I tried these. I guess I can't find what I want. Below is the block of code I tried to sort. I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what happened.

```
SORT it_char DESCENDING.
LOOP AT it_char INTO wa_char.
  WRITE :/ wa_char.
ENDLOOP.

skip 2.

SORT it_char ASCENDING.
LOOP AT it_char INTO wa_char.
  WRITE :/ wa_char.
ENDLOOP.
```

I set the variable type to c but it doesn't work correctly in double digit numbers.

my parameters screen:

[image: my parameters screen]

my report screen:

[image: my report screen]

Answer (score 2):

In order to sort an internal table, use the [SORT keyword](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapsort_itab.htm).

To sort a table of strings or type C alphabetically, use:

```
SORT it_char ASCENDING AS TEXT.
```

When the line type of the table is numerical and you want to sort from large to small:

```
SORT it_char DESCENDING.
```

More information can also be found in [this help article](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_ewm2007/helpdata/en/fc/eb3800358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm?no_cache=true).